# What does the | (pipe) mean at the start of a type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tslint

```
interface MyInterface {     
    someConst:
    | {
        fullName: string
        email: string
      }
    | null
    | undefined
}
```

My tslint (my linter) added the **first** | here for me.

I know that the second and third | are a union type but what does the first | do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically tslint making the code prettier to read, it is inconsequential to the type and should be ignored, there should be a tslint rule you could tweak - if I had access to it, maybe I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Its optional, it doesnt do anything at all. If you send me your tslint, I might give it a look and try to find the rule.